# Reprogram Arduino Mega 2560 using Duemilanove?

Tags: bootloader, isp

Experiencing that Mega 2560 uploading problem. Tried updating the IDE, worked for a while but symptoms went back. Now i want to reprogram that chip.

I'm asking this question cuz hardware ain't free and shipping is not instant.

I don't have a programmer. So we already know that we can program an arduino board with another arduino board as a programmer. However i just have a Duemilanove available. Will this work? Please do not answer if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can follow this tutorial: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11635
The uno is basically the same as the Duemilanove